# Problem with a mutable Map in Scala with var keyword

Tags: scala

I don't really understand the following situation :

```
object Social extends App {

def add(repo: Map[String, Set[String]], name: String) =
    repo + (name -> Set())

var r = Map[String, Set[String]]()

println(add(r, "Jim"))
```

This way, everyting works fine.
But if I try to reaffect r, the program doesn't compile anymore :

```
var r = Map[String, Set[String]]()
r = add(r, "Jim") // problem

println(add(r, "Jim"))
```

There is now a type mismatch :

```
[error] /Users/pom/workspace/coursera/example/src/main/scala.     /example/Social.scala:7: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,scala.collection.immutable.Set[_ <: String]]
[error]  required: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Set[String]]
```

Why is the inference changing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes the compiler can't figure out the intended type of an empty collection.

This will fix it.

```
repo + (name -> Set.empty[String])
```

Comment: Thank you! It's annoying the compiler doesn't emphasize the line in the add method, it would have helped me...